# How do I count the number of rows in a MySQL Table?

Tags: php, mysql

I know that inside MySQL, you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

I have written the following code in PHP to display the number of rows on the page:

```
$sql = 'select * from users';
$data = $conn -> query($sql);
echo $data;
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in [Directory] on line 19.

I think the problem is that the returned value is not in string form. If that is correct, how would I be able to display the number of rows on the page?

Comment: Which API are you using? Objects are typically returend and there are a number of row counting methods depending on the API.

Comment: I am using a PDO for the database connection.

Comment: @merlinWang , so why fetch the whole data set if you arent gonna use it anyway? `Count()` sound much better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to count the rows you can do this with PDO:

```
$sql = 'select * from users';
$data = $conn->query($sql);
$rows = $data->fetchAll();
$num_rows = count($rows);
```

Comment: @jay Blanchard , i dont assume to know what the SO wanted but the question title seemed to be off with the sample code that he gave. But that's been rectified.

Comment: Yeah, there was a bit of a mismatch there @PlatinumIndustries. I went with what was in the body.

Comment: @jayBlanchard , noted. Nice tutorials btw, I went through them a long while back.

Comment: Thanks @PlatinumIndustries, I am writing more and more these days. I just need to finish some of them!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you arent badly off, you are almost there:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as numrow FROM users';
$data = $conn -> query($sql);
rows = $data->fetchAll();
```

Depending on the type of return data, you could use

`$rows->numrow` if the return data is an object

Comment: It appears to return as an object, not an array, but when I put `echo $data -> numrow; I get a message saying  Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$numrow in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 19

Comment: @MerlinWang you might want to fetch the data first, i've made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

There are some easy and faster way to do this

1. **COUNT** the column in query and fetch

> $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS total_row FROM table_name";
>   $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
>   $stmt->execute();
>   echo $count['total_row'];

2. Using **rowCount()**

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
>   $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
>   $stmt->execute();
>   $count = $stmt->rowCount();
>   echo $count;